# Angular 14 styling pseudo elements using CSS variables

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a radio button that I want to style and I am trying to style pseudo elements using CSS variables in Angular. But I am not seeing any changes. What I have done:

**radio.component.html**

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" [attr.name]="radioGroupName" />
    <span [ngStyle]="{'--my-var': 'inset 0 0 0 0.125em #212121'}"></span>
</label>
```

My TS file

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef, Component, Input, OnInit, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-radio-button',
    templateUrl: './radio-button.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./radio-button.component.scss'],
    // changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class RadioButtonComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() radioGroupName: any;
    constructor(private _changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
    ngOnInit(): void {
    }


}
```

My **radio.component.scss** file

```
label span:before {
    display: flex;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    content: "";
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 1.5em;
    height: 1.5em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 0.375em;
    transition: 0.25s ease;
    --my-var: inset 0 0 0 0.125em #00005c;
    box-shadow: var(--my-var);
}
```

Is it not possible to style pseudo elements in Angular anymore? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of initializing CSS variable inside `span:before` pesduo selector initialize inside parent element

```
label{
  --my-var: inset 0 0 0 0.125em #00005c; 
}
```

Then use style attribute binding to change CSS variable dynamically

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" [attr.name]="radioGroupName" />
    <span [style.--my-var]="'inset 0 0 0 0.125em #212121'"></span>
</label>
```

**[Sample Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-izbvas?file=src/app/app.component.html)**